# Set the status bar to black colour

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistatusbar

I want to set the colour of the `status bar` (The small strip on top where the clock and battery is displayed) to black background  with white text. How can I do this ?

[image]

My approach so far :

I added the following in the `info.plist`

```
View controller-based status bar appearance --> NO
```

and in the `viewController`

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleDefault;
}
```

However, the style does not change.  How can I make the status bar black?

Comment: Why to set `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `NO`? Are you sure you don't want `YES` there, considering you are using a view controller to provide the style?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Xcode 8 / iOS 10 / Swift 3:

Change the status bar background color temporarily on one view by adding a colored UIView under the status bar. I put these lines in `viewWillAppear()`. my tint is white with 45% transparency, but you can put in any opaque or transparent UIColor value.

```
let statusView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:     self.view.bounds.width, height: 20))
statusView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.45)
 self.view.addSubview(statusView)
```

You can add your statusView to the navigationController, instead of the view, if you have a navigation controller on the view.

You can also pass in UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width for the width of the  simulated status bar background view. Do not hardcode a width, otherwise it wont fit all devices properly.

Alternatively, you can also change the status bar background throughout your app using this code. be aware that if even if placed in `viewWillAppear()`, not `viewDidLoad()`, other views will still adopt the altered status bar when you navigate forward/back.

```
let statWindow = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey:"statusBarWindow") as! UIView
let statusBar = statWindow.subviews[0] as UIView
statusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.45)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can make the text white by calling:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: true)
```

The status bar has a transparent background. There is no way of changing that. You can pin a view underneath it to act as a background.

Comment: How can I make the navigation bar start from the status bar ? So if my navigation bar is black then the status will also look like its black. How can this be done ?

Comment: Use a navigation bar that is associated with a navigation controller. For example in your storyboard click on the view controller you want to have a navigation bar on. Then click editor->embed in -> navigation controller. Then click on Navigation Controller Scene, click on Navigation Bar then change Bar Tint in the inspector to black.

Comment: Or `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()`

Comment: How do I reduce the height of the Navigation bar ?

Answer (score 2):

**You need to follow 3 steps in Xcode-8.1 and iOS 10:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

So finally we can get the desired result:

[image]

Comment: @Natalia Chodelski : Do you think why you downvote or just downvoated for no reason. By downVoting you are just showing immature Coding. You can edit my answer and show the updated  screenshot . Show the difference in it . Which will reflect real Team spirit :)  Thanks.

Comment: I downvoted your answer for a couple reasons: you posted a picture, not code, which i felt was less useful to programmers that come across it since it cannot be copied. Also accuracy - the first line in the .plist screenshot `view controller based status bar appearance = NO' isn't doing anything here because you're actually adding a colored subview on top of the main view under the status bar, not controlling the status bar theme via it's API methods.

Comment: This line would stop the theming effect from working using normal status bar api methods because it's actually telling the app that the global status bar theme should control all status bar appearances, but you bypass that with the code by adding a subview underneath. And the 3rd line from the .plist screenshot isn't doing anything either  `UIStatusbarStyle.lightContent` should make the status bar text white, but instead the same grey color of the background view is showing thru. So that line is pointless too.

Comment: Lastly, the simulated status bar background view you create should not be hardcoded to a width, you should pass in the width using the width of your view or `UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width` so that it fits all devices properly. Oh and you can add the colored view to the view if you dont have a navigationController, which is a pretty common use case.

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution:

Go to your main storyboard (the one that gets loaded when the app starts, after the splash is done), and change the background color of the top-level `UIView` to black.

If you need the rest of the screen to have another colored background, just create another `UIView` as a subview of the top-level view, set its frame to start beneath the top-layout-guide, and set its color to whatever color you need.

You would still need to set the plist flags as mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

**Goto Plist file**

```
a) Set the value "View controller-based status bar appearance" to NO
b) Set the value "Status bar style" to UIStatusBarStyleLightContent 

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(version)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:version options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)

    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0"))
    {
        UIView *view=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 20)];
        view.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:view];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

It fixed status bar color for me. Hope it helps.