# Changing status bar background

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, statusbar, uicolor

I want the status bar to have a darker tone than the navigation bar? how can i implement this in Swift 2.0 in IOS 9
An exmaple is as attached:[image]

I am able to turn the status bars text to white but not the background to a darker tone then the navigation bar? Would i need to a add a separate view over it? And if so how because i cant get it on top of the navigation bar?

Comment: This could help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26956728/changing-the-status-bar-color-for-specific-viewcontrollers-using-swift-in-ios8

Comment: Your not understanding my problem, i already know how to change the status bar text to light i need to change the background colour which is different from the navigation background

Comment: Well what's the code that you've tried?

Comment: I havnt tried to change the background because i cant find a way, i just know how to change the status bar colour to whi9te through the attributes inspecotr

Comment: for Xcode 8.1 :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36207499/set-the-status-bar-to-black-colour/41124747#41124747

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer:

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 20))
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(view)
```

Comment: I found the solution thanks to Hodson

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a new `UIView` and set it to the appropriate colour. Either give it a frame or add constraints so it sits at the top.

Its height should be the height of the status bar (which is usually 20 I believe but you can get this programatically as well just incase it changes...or isn't present.)

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height
```

Comment: Tried but i cant get it to go over the navigation bar?

Comment: Even if you set the frame as such: `let view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 20))` it still doesn't show above the navigation bar? Note: 500 if too much for width, you should set that to the actual screen width but for quickness, I just set it to a large number (bigger than the screen width).

Comment: THANK YOU! But to add if anyone else has the problem, run this:

Comment: `view.layer.zPosition = 100` can help if it's not showing