# Navigation bar hidden, move remaining view under status bar

Tags: ios

I have navigation controller hidden in one of the controller. That controller shows default status bar instead of moving view under the status bar. Here I need to hide navigation bar and move remaining view under status bar. I am looking for solution for this situation. If anyone has faced similar problem please help.

[image]

Comment: can you show some code ? or some screenshot of that..

Comment: Here, I need same grey colour of view in status bar.

Comment: may be this one helps you.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36207499/set-the-status-bar-to-black-colour

Comment: Try this in appDelegate UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent and info.plist set `View controller-based status bar appearance` to no

Comment: Tried this solution already. No luck!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click drop-down arrow on Top, **Select Current view** option. - It will **Start from Status bar**
   [image]

Comment: I have the same problem. But the solution does not work for me because constraints are not available for the view of the view controller. How can I solve this?